# reactivecocoa observe global variable

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

I have defined globalUser as a global variable in A.swift file. How to observe globalUser's changes in B.swift.

```
// A.swift
var globalUser: Dictionary<String, Any?>? = nil


// B.swift
class MeViewController: UITableViewController {
    var user: Dictionary<String, Any?>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // how to bind user with globalUser using ReactiveCocoa? Or Observing globalUser's changing, to update user
    }

}
```

````

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

wrap the globalUser in a MutableProperty and observe that:

```
// A.swift
let globalUser: MutableProperty<[String: Any]?> = MutableProperty(nil)

// B.swift
class MeViewController: UITableViewController {
    var user: [String, Any]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        reactive[\.user] <~ globalUser
    }
}
```